# How I can run “mapbox-gl-native” project?

Tags: ios, mapbox

I’m using “Mapbox-iOS-SDK” 3.0 via cocoapods and want implement pulsing effect for annotations:
https://github.com/TransitApp/SVPulsingAnnotationView

By this link was suggested update MGLMapView.mm file:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33598363/implement-pulse-effect-on-annotations-in-mapbox/33768054#33768054

But for now I don’t understand how I can run “mapbox-gl-native” project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here are the instructions](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/45a0f48ea023a73d8652c6c2af94f7048a02157c/platform/ios/DEVELOPING.md) for setting up a Mapbox iOS SDK build environment. Essentially, you clone the repo and run `make iproj`. Once you're ready to integrate the library into your own app, you'd run `make ipackage` and copy the resulting binary/etc in `build/ios/dynamic/` to your project.

**Beware**: the `mapbox-gl-native` project is very complicated to build, the structure still in flux, and heavy development happening every day, so any instructions that I write here are likely to not be entirely useful in the mid-future.

Adding native views to a map view is not easily accomplished (yet), but you would start [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/45a0f48ea023a73d8652c6c2af94f7048a02157c/platform/ios/src/MGLMapView.mm) and modify/subclass/imitate [`MGLUserLocationAnnotationView`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/45a0f48ea023a73d8652c6c2af94f7048a02157c/platform/ios/src/MGLUserLocationAnnotationView.m).